# Using COUNTIFS for a series of values at once

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Working a step higher then COUNTIFS, I appose a challenge to write a formula without VBA code. The basic data is combined from 1000s of rows with:

- Column A: rows with values from 1 to 3
- Column B: rows with values from 1 to 250.

For this purpose lets say, we are looking at all cells of value "1" in column A, that suit value "5" in column B. To find all matches, we'd use COUNTIFS command.

```
1   1
2   5
1   5
1   7
1   10
3   45
2   12
1   2
2   1

=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;5)
```

The answer here is 1.

Next thing, the "5" in column B belongs to a group, e.g. group from 1 to 9. What would the best way be, to count all the matches in this example, so that for all "1"'s in column A, we'd have to find all matches with values from 1 to 9 in column B?! In the upper example that would result in "4". The obvious solution is with a series of IF commands, but that's unefficient and it easy to make a mistake, that get's easily overseen.

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;"<="&9)
```

Works only as the upper limit. If I give the third criteria range and condition as ">="&1 it does not work - returns 0.

I noticed that three criteria ranges and conditions work only if I use "=" sign in a condition. As soon as I use

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;"<="&9,B1:B9;">=1")
```

it returns 0. My goal is to eventualy replace the number in a condition with a VLOOKUP command, so the final equation should be smth like

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;1;B1:B9;"<="&VLOOKUP(...),B1:B9;">=VLOOKUP(...)")
```

But the "<" and ">" signs mess with this. Still looking for a solution.

Gasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. Strange and not [as specified](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53c4dc8e-0e5b-4e32-93df-9ca5e7da89ed) by Microsoft. I tried to reproduce the problem, but on Excel 2011 for Mac as well as on Excel 2010 for Windows it works as expected using the following formula: `=COUNTIFS(A1:A9;E1;B1:B9;">="&E2;B1:B9;"<="&E3)` (I used three cells for the lookup values you want to use).

[image: Excel worksheet using countifs]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @agtoever! It works, I just realized my problems is somewhere else. This is my entire code:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("baza!$";SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH("card_type_id";baza!$A$1:$AAA$1;0);4);"1";"");"$2:$";SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH("card_type_id";baza!$A$1:$AAA$1;0);4);"1";"");"$15000"));1;INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("baza!$";SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(IF($C$4="CC_SI_klasifikacija";"building_classification_id";0);baza!$A$1:$AAA$1;0);4);"1";"");"$2:$";SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;MATCH(IF($C$4="CC_SI_klasifikacija";"building_classification_id";0);baza!$A$1:$AAA$1;0);4);"1";"");"$15000"));"<="&VLOOKUP(C5;K203:N210;4;FALSE))
```

The problems is, that my second criteria range is not recognized as numbers in cells (picture below). If you look at the formula - this is the N column. Is it even possible to convert the text into a number within one formula? e.g. NUMBERVALUE ?

http://shrani.si/f/1C/Kx/mAYK9Wz/textnumber.jpg

Comment: The [VALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/VALUE-function-fd94fddd-e3ef-483b-8575-c7a3d01ff831) converts text to a value. As an alternative, you can convert the entire column to values in the sheet using the the "[Split data to columns](https://support.office.com/article/split-text-into-different-cells-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)"-function, where you can convert one column of numbers-as-text to one column of numbers.

Comment: Yeah, i know that is an option. But is it possible just to define that values in this column should be read as numbers and not text? NUMBERVALUE offers this option, but only for a single value - not range of them.

Comment: The two options I gave are the only two ways that I know.